# How to match elements from multiple columns from df1 with values from an array1 in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to match elements from `V1` and `V2` of `df1` with values from an `array1`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1 = c('A','S','E','E','V','G','H','P','K','L','W','N','P','A','A','S','E','N','M','Y','S','G','D','R','H'),
V2 = c('E','D','S','N','A','K','K','R','P','L','W','D','A','C','A','P','E','Y','W','Y','D','D','R','E','M'))


array1

     1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11  12   13  14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25
A 0.15 0.00 0.10 0.10 0.05 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00
C 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
D 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.10 0.00 0.05 0.05 0.00 0.0 0.10 0.0 0.00 0.25 0.10 0.20 0.10 0.00 0.15 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.05
E 0.05 0.10 0.05 0.05 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.10 0.10 0.20 0.00 0.0 0.05 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.10 0.00 0.20 0.10 0.05 0.15 0.10 0.10
F 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.0 0.05 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
G 0.00 0.00 0.10 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00
H 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
I 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.2 0.05 0.1 0.05 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
K 0.00 0.10 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.10 0.00 0.05
L 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.10 0.00 0.10 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.2 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00
M 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
N 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00
P 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.05 0.00 0.10 0.10 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.10 0.00 0.05 0.00
Q 0.00 0.05 0.05 0.00 0.10 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.0 0.00 0.1 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05
R 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.05 0.15 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
S 0.10 0.10 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.15 0.10 0.20 0.05 0.10 0.10 0.05 0.00 0.05 0.05 0.10
T 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.05 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.00
V 0.05 0.05 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.05 0.00 0.10 0.2 0.15 0.0 0.15 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
W 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
Y 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.10 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
```

The expected outcome can be a list or a df:

```
V1   0.15, 0.10, 0.05, 0.05, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.10, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.10, 0.05, 0.05, 0.00, 0.00, 0.05, 0.05, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
V2 ...
```

That works perfectly, when I have just 'V1' to match:

```
array1[cbind(match(df1, rownames(array1)), 1:ncol(array1))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sapply`/`lapply` to match every column in the dataframe.

```
sapply(df1, function(x) array1[cbind(match(x, rownames(array1)), 1:ncol(array1))])
```